# Формат serialize array?

Tags: php

Как использовать этот запрос с помощью PHP?

Результат запроса:

```
a:10:{s:6:"EURUSD";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"EURUSD";s:3:"bid";s:6:"1.3143";s:3:"ask";s:6:"1.3146";s:6:"change";s:7:"-0.0001";s:6:"digits";s:1:"4"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"GBPUSD";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"GBPUSD";s:3:"bid";s:6:"1.5465";s:3:"ask";s:6:"1.5468";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0001";s:6:"digits";s:1:"4"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"USDJPY";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"USDJPY";s:3:"bid";s:7:"83.4800";s:3:"ask";s:7:"83.5100";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0000";s:6:"digits";s:1:"2"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"USDCHF";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"USDCHF";s:3:"bid";s:6:"0.9528";s:3:"ask";s:6:"0.9531";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0001";s:6:"digits";s:1:"4"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"USDCAD";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"USDCAD";s:3:"bid";s:6:"1.0130";s:3:"ask";s:6:"1.0133";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0001";s:6:"digits";s:1:"4"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"EURJPY";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"EURJPY";s:3:"bid";s:8:"109.7300";s:3:"ask";s:8:"109.7600";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0100";s:6:"digits";s:1:"2"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"EURCHF";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"EURCHF";s:3:"bid";s:6:"1.2520";s:3:"ask";s:6:"1.2523";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0001";s:6:"digits";s:1:"4"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"GBPJPY";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"GBPJPY";s:3:"bid";s:8:"129.0800";s:3:"ask";s:8:"129.1500";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0100";s:6:"digits";s:1:"2"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:6:"GBPCHF";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:6:"GBPCHF";s:3:"bid";s:6:"1.4729";s:3:"ask";s:6:"1.4736";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.0001";s:6:"digits";s:1:"4"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023283";} s:4:"GOLD";a:6:{s:6:"symbol";s:4:"GOLD";s:3:"bid";s:9:"1389.8000";s:3:"ask";s:9:"1390.8000";s:6:"change";s:6:"0.1001";s:6:"digits";s:1:"2"; s:8:"lasttime";s:10:"1293023276";}}
```

Это результат запроса forex котировок.

Ссылка на [сайт](http://partners.instaforex.com/ru/quotes_description.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newArray=unserialize($vash_text);

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Не думаю, что он должен отображаться в том виде в каком написан. Это котировки постоянно обновляются и на сайте должны обновляться...

Comment: Это я вам показал просто, чтобы вам видно было, что за данные вы привели в вопросе. Получив массив, вы обновляете свой сайт, подставляя данные с массива $newArray.

Comment: Данные должны обновляться постоянно. 
Хорошо. Спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Данные обновлять должны Вы сами. Ваш скрипт. Передайте эти данные скрипту, unserialize-ируйте, обновите сайт.

Answer (score 2):

[unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) ?